# How to prevent users from deleting contacts but allowing merging of contacts

Tags: trigger, delete, merge

Need the ability to prevent users in a profile to be able to merge contacts but prevent them from clicking on delete button from contact detail screen and from related lists.

In before delete event, I am unable to identify whether the record was from merge or delete operation.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this in a trigger. Instead:

1. Create a VF page with a page action method to invoke a Contact Controller extension method `deleteRedirect()`
2. If the running user's profile is not allowed to do deletes, redirect to a VF page that displays a pageMessage "Sorry, deletes not possible" plus a Cancel button that takes the user back to the Contact detail page
3. If the running user's profile can delete the Contact, simply execute DML to delete and then redirect back to the value of retURL parameter.
4. Override the standard Contact delete button with your new VF page

Or variations on the above

Comment: Thanks for an alternate approach, but I am looking for a non vf solution.

Comment: Thanks for an alternate approach, but I am looking for a non vf solution.

Comment: as Trigger operates at the database level, per Separation of Concerns, it should not have to be aware of context of invocation